# Does Qt Timer API stop and terminate the running slot? And how can I make it wait to get the timer slot execution completed?

Tags: c++, qt, timer, qt5

I have just started working with QT, and found the nice feature of QTTimer which triggers the slot at the interval of given period.  Some point in time, I  came across two situations.

1)  if the timer is in the pending state, stopping timer have no issues that i won't even move to 'running state'.

2) If the timer is already running ( assume it is a bit long process task), then i found the stop will not terminate/stop 'running state'.

**My Question:**

At any given point of time, if stop is invoked, i should make sure it is stopped if it is already running.

Example:

```
connect(&myTimer,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(missionStarted()));
```

When i Stop like this:

```
   myTimer.stop() -> It actually stops the next firing the signal, but it does not stop running state of missionStarted().
```

**What i thought of a solution ?**

```
   myTimer.stop();
   while (myTimer.isActive()) {

   }
   qDebug()<<" I am guaranteed that missionStarted() is no more running, will not run anymore" ;
```

Is the solution is a way to go?. please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Qt Timer API stop and terminate the running slot?

No. The timer stop does not terminate running slot.

> And how can I make it wait to get the timer slot execution completed?

There several ways to do so: with the signal back to the object that has the timer, for instance:

```
void MyWorkerClass::mySlot()
{
   doTheJob();
   emit signalIamDone();
}
```

And the the object that has the timer can acknowledge the slot stopped by connecting to that `signalIamDone`:

```
connect(&workerObj, SIGNAL(signalIamDone()), &managerObj, SLOT(workerJobDoneSlot()));
```

The actual slot:

```
void MyManagerClass::workerJobDoneSlot()
{
   doSomethingOnJobFinished();
}
```

I would also try to use [condition variable wait](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-threads-waitconditions-example.html) if you had a manager and worker thread but it seems like everything is running on one main UI thread.

- And mind that usually the worker slot is getting called on the same main thread as your manager object runs unless your manager object is specifically running in the context of own thread. So, unless told otherwise about threads, you always have it waiting on the slot finishing you just need to know that the wait is over or `doSomethingOnJobFinished` called.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I see the point in your answer. However, will the approach i mentioned in the Question is valid ?

Comment: You cannot run the code in two functions on one thread at the same time. Not valid. Single-threaded example is like my answer or similar. And multi-threaded example would be different.